# About de Rham Cohomology and complex differential forms on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

I try to compute the de Rham cohomology of the complex projective spaces $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ without using Mayer-Vietoris sequence but only using definiton of the de Rham cohomology, i.e. the quotient vector space $\{k$-closed form$/ k$-exact form$\}$.

Firstly, I take $\{U_i\}$ as the standard affine cover of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$, then try to coincide $k$-form$^\ast$ on the intersections, and hope to arrive that (*)for $k$ is odd, every closed $k$-form is also exact $k$-form to conclude that cohomology group is trivial.
(**)for $k$ is even, i know that from Fubini-Study form $\omega$ gives that there is an unique $2$-form on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$, and generates other cohomology groups. But i do not know the proof that $\omega^k$ is unique $2k$ form which generates other related cohomology group.

My question is that there is a way to do that showing all closed $k$-forms are also exact when $k$ is odd?

Would you mind if i ask you to explain?

$\ast$ where $k$-form $(p,q)$-types and $k=p+q$

https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=KpMwNHhrj9IC&pg=PA26&dq=complex+differential+forms+on+projective+space&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO54vl-rrQAhVD1xoKHaInCvUQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=complex%20differential%20forms%20on%20projective%20space&f=false

Comment: It seems like you want to do a Cech cohomology argument. Is that right??

Comment: yes  dear Alex, it is a Cech cohomology argument of kind.

Comment: When you speak of the "unique" $2$-form $\omega$, in what sense are you using the term _unique_? (For what it's worth, I'd expect the direct approach you outline to be painful and unenlightening. For starters, there is an infinite-dimensional space of smooth (even positive) real $2$-forms each of which generates second cohomology, and whose exterior powers generate the higher even-dimensional cohomology.)

Comment: Dear Andrew, i mean about unique in a sense that [$\omega$] are unique up to cohomology class of $\omega$. Yes Andrew, you are right, i found this approach is tedious and painful at the beginning, then hope that i could find other $(2k+1)$-form on $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$. i learned from your answer to some questions, there are lots of global differentials. When we identify  $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ with \mathbb{S}^2, we can arrive fubini-study metric. How can we do that for k is odd in higher dimension? even though it is messy, at least i want to see for $n=2,3$. Thank you for enlightening.

Comment: Just asking: Have you written up the case $n = 1$ (every closed $1$-form on the complex projective line is exact) using your intended strategy? If so, have you written up the details for $1$-forms on $\mathbf{CP}^{2}$ and $\mathbf{CP}^{3}$?

Comment: yes Sir, i did this since identifying $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ with $\mathbb{S}^2$, i can see every closed $1$ form becomes exact $1$ form, but i cant see how can i do on higher dimensions since i have no longer have identification. Complex differential form given by a sum of (p,q) types, so  $1$ form consists of $dz_i$ and $bar{dz_i}$. How can i show that this form defined on all \mathbf{CP}^{n} and also closed to conclude that it is also exact.

Comment: to add up, on the intersections of open cover, i supposed, using transition formula for a k-form between two charts, i hope to arrive some conclusion, but this no longer real case, these are not independent.