# cohomology of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ and $\mathbb{RP}^m$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes

How to obtain the cohomology of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ and $\mathbb{RP}^m$, and what are the precise answers:

$$
H^i(\mathbb{CP}^n,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\text{?}
$$

$$
H^i(\mathbb{CP}^n,\mathbb{Z} )=\text{?}
$$

$$
H^i(\mathbb{RP}^n,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\text{?}
$$

$$
H^i(\mathbb{RP}^n,\mathbb{Z} )=\text{?}
$$

Comment: Have you tried searching stack exchange? There are many good posts covering this.

Comment: I have found some partial answers but not the full one: e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721659/de-rham-cohomology-of-t-mathbbcpn

Comment: If you know the full answers, please feel free point out. Thank you

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025055/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the cohomology of $\mathbb{CP}^{n}$: https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Cohomology_of_complex_projective_space

$$
H^p(\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C});M) = \left\lbrace\begin{array}{rl} M, & \qquad p \text{ even, } 0 \le p \le 2n\\ 0, & \qquad \text{otherwise} \end{array}\right.
$$

find the cohomology of $\mathbb{RP}^{n}$: 
https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Cohomology_of_real_projective_space

$$
H^p(\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R}); M) = \left\lbrace \begin{array}{rl} M, & \qquad p=0,n\\ M/2M, &\qquad p \text{ even, } 0 < p < n\\ T, & \qquad p \text{ odd, } 0 < p < n \\ 0, & \qquad \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.
$$
Here $M$ is an Abelian group.

Here $T$ denotes the $2$-torsion subgroup, i.e., the subgroup comprising elements of order dividing $2.$

Comment: Thanks, but what is $T$ precisely? Is that $T=H^2(...)$ ?

Comment: What is the subgroup comprising elements of order dividing 2?

Comment: Often using \text{} where \operatorname{} is appropriate happens here. This was an instance of the opposite error. In some very simple contexts they yield identical results, but one should understand that they don't always, and that's why these are two different things.