# $2$-torsion subgroup of $M$ v.s. $M/(2M)$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, torsion-groups

From this question/answer, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2843091/141334, 
I learned the word that $T$ denotes the $2$-torsion subgroup, i.e., the subgroup comprising elements of order dividing $2.$

What is the $T$ afterall defined? Can one give some example, say $M=\mathbb{Z}_n$ as a cyclice group of order $n$?

Is it correct  to say that $T$ denotes the $2$-torsion subgroup of $G$, which means the
$$T=H^1(M,\mathbb{Z})/(2 H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}))?$$

How does this $T$ compare to 
$$
M/(2M)?
$$
Say, when $M$ is abelian or not?

For example in this table from https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Cohomology_of_real_projective_space

[image]

> question: When $M=\mathbb{Z}_n$ where $n$ is any integer (like $M=\mathbb{Z}_2$) or $M=\mathbb{Z}$, what are the entries of $T$ becomes?

Comment: Don't know if this is exactly what you're asking for but: Given a module $M$ over a ring $R$, a $p$-torsion submodule for $p\in R$ is defined as $M[p]=\{m \in M : (\exists  n\in \mathbb N_0) , p^nm=0 \}$. The special case where a $M$ is an abelian group, is when you consider consider it as a $\mathbb Z$-module

Comment: Thanks, let us try an exanple, if $M=\mathbb{Z}_n$ with $n$ an even integer, what is the 2-torsion of $M=\mathbb{Z}_n$ ?

Comment: maybe you can post the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Given a module $M$ over a ring $R$, a $p$-torsion submodule for $p\in R$ is defined as $M[p]=\{m \in M : (\exists  n\in \mathbb N_0) , p^nm=0 \}$. The special case where a $M$ is an abelian group, is when you consider consider it as a $\mathbb Z$-module

As for the question when the module is $\mathbb Z_n$ then the $2$-torsion should be:

If $2 \not \mid n$ then $\mathbb Z_n[2]=\{0\}$

and if $2\mid n$ write $n=2^rq$ (where $2 \not \mid q$)

**Edit**:$$\mathbb Z_n[2]=\{m \in \mathbb Z_n : (\exists  k\in \mathbb N_0) , 2^km=0 \}$$
Notice that $(2:q)=1$ therefore using the chinese remainder theorem we have the following: $$\mathbb Z_n = \mathbb Z_{2^r} \oplus \mathbb Z_q$$ and using this decomposition we have $\mathbb Z_n [2] \simeq \mathbb Z_{2^r}$

Comment: Thanks , I voted up, but I am confused

Comment: By $ 2^km \equiv 0(n)$, do you mean that  $2^km \equiv 0 \quad (\mod n)$?

Comment: It looks a bit confusing what you wrote, if you can choose $n=2,4,8,10$ as examples, I may know what you really write

Comment: Moreover, this should be addressed: > >question: When $M=\mathbb{Z}_n$ where $n$ is any integer (like $M=\mathbb{Z}_2$) or $M=\mathbb{Z}$, what are the entries of $T$ becomes?

Comment: When $M= \mathbb Z$ there are no such $p$-torsion elements (apart from $0$) and one general way to see this is to note that $\mathbb Z$ as a module over itself is a free module generated by $\{1\}$ and free modules are torsion-free. For the last part I don't quite understand what do you mean by "what the entries of $T$ become"

Comment: Gonna edit to add a better solution

Comment: @Ron, For $\mathbb{Z}_8$, you said "With this example, it is easy to see that such elements are {0,2,4}", shouldn't it be {0,1,2,4} instead?

Comment: For $\mathbb{Z}_8$, if it {0,1,2,4}, this is a group or not? In the OP by annie heart, it looks that she is asking the "cohomology group" written in terms of $T$ as 2-torsion. So I suppose it has to be a group?

Comment: Also, you write $$\mathbb{Z}_n[2] \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{2^r},$$ but for 
$$\mathbb{Z}_8[2] \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{2^3}=\mathbb{Z}_8?$$
So it is not what you commented  {0,2,4} or {0,1,2,4} at all?

Comment: Should it be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group ?

Comment: Yes @wonderich, before the edit what I thought had some errors. But my "answer" was only supposed to a comment on the definition of p-torsion, but OP then asked to post an answer on the example of $ \mathbb Z_n$. I'm gonna delete my previous comments as they might be incorrect

Comment: I am not sure your answer, is that 
$\mathbb Z_n [2] \simeq \mathbb Z_{2^r}$
means 
$$\mathbb Z_8 [2] \simeq \mathbb Z_{2^3}=\mathbb Z_8?$$ for $n=8?$ But did not you just say that we only select $\{0,1,2,4\}$?

Comment: @annieheart I'm sorry but last time my argument had some errors. I fixed it and the last edit uses the decomposition of a module in it's $p$-torsion submodules, (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification).

Comment: I have no troubles to understand the decomposition. I had trouble to understand your last line and the three lines above the last

Comment: You said: $$\mathbb Z_n[2]=\{m \in \mathbb Z_n : (\exists  k\in \mathbb N_0) , 2^km=0 \}$$and also $$\mathbb Z_n [2] \simeq \mathbb Z_{2^r}.$$ However, the earlier one suggests $\mathbb Z_n[2]=\{0,1,2,4\}$. But does $3,5,7$ also satisfies the condition if we choose the natural number $k=3$, so $ 2^k=2^3=8$? What is the restriction of natural number?

Comment: Isnt that $3*8=5*8=7*8= 0 \mod 8$?

Comment: I am worried that $\mathbb Z_n[2]=\{m \in \mathbb Z_n : (\exists  k\in \mathbb N_0) , 2^km=0 \}$ is not the correct definition, maybe one needs the $k$ is not just a natural number, but smaller than the $k<r$ , if $n=2^r*q$?

Comment: In short, two things you said are not consistent with each other, if we just check $n=8$

Comment: @annieheart Yeah as you said any element of $\mathbb Z_8$ has order divisible by $2$ and it does satisfy the definition of $2$-torsion if we consider $\mathbb Z_8$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module

Comment: @annieheart You can check the definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_subgroup#p-power_torsion_subgroups